# Combine values from different foreach loop into an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to combine two `foreach()` loop values into an array and display it in a single table. Both of them have the same field, but how can i display it in a single table instead of having two different tables?

```
<tr>
   <th> ID </th>
   <th> Transaction Type </th>
</tr>
<tbody>
   <?php 
      $ch = new CommissionHelper($rep);
      $data = $ch->getTransactionRecords($member);
        foreach ($data as $record ) {
      $d = ((object)$record);
      $pt = round($d->point, 2);
      ?>
   <tr>
      <td><?php echo $d->id;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d->type;?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php
      }
      ?>
</tbody>
<tr>
   <th> ID </th>
   <th> Transaction Type </th>
</tr>
<tbody>
   <?php 
      $query = "SELECT * FROM invoice_withdraw_debit_card where user_ID like $id";
      $data = $MySQLi_CON->query($query);
      foreach ($data as $key ) {      
      ?>
   <tr>
      <td><?php echo $key['invoice_ID'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $key['type'];?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php
      }
      ?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it like below:-

```
<tr>
   <th> ID </th>
   <th> Transaction Type </th>
</tr>
<tbody>
   <?php 
      $ch = new CommissionHelper($rep);
      $data = $ch->getTransactionRecords($member);
        foreach ($data as $record ) {
      $d = ((object)$record);
      $pt = round($d->point, 2);
      ?>
   <tr>
      <td><?php echo $d->id;?></td>
      <td><?php echo $d->type;?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php
      }
      ?>
   <?php 
      $query = "SELECT * FROM invoice_withdraw_debit_card where user_ID like $id";
      $data = $MySQLi_CON->query($query);
      foreach ($data as $key ) {      
      ?>
   <tr>
      <td><?php echo $key['invoice_ID'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $key['type'];?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php
      }
      ?>
</tbody>
```

Note:- remove `</tbody><tr><th> ID </th><th> Transaction Type </th></tr><tbody>` from the middle of your code

Comment: fypforstack glad to help you. Cheers :):):)